# No midi ports available

Tags: c++, ubuntu, midi

I am trying to configure my midi settings so that I can have midi IO in my laptop.
I am starting timidity with the following:

```
jackd -R -P 70 -d alsa -p 256 -n 3 -r 44100
```

then by doing

```
aplaymidi -l
```

I get:

```
Port    Client name                      Port name
14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
128:0    TiMidity                         TiMidity port 0
128:1    TiMidity                         TiMidity port 1
128:2    TiMidity                         TiMidity port 2
128:3    TiMidity                         TiMidity port 3
```

It seems that there are 4 ports available on the timidity server. However when I try to find output port, nothing is found by my C++ app (it uses the Rtmidi library).

```
int main(){

RtMidiOut *midiout = 0;
midiout = new RtMidiOut();
std::vector<unsigned char> message;
midiout->openVirtualPort();

unsigned int nPorts = midiout->getPortCount();

if (nPorts == 0) {
    std::cout << "No ports available!\n";
    return;
}
std::cout << "\nThere are " << nPorts << " MIDI output ports available.\n";
}
```

Comment: I'd guess there's a bug in your C++ application, but you've not shown us anything from that at all so it's impossible to say more. Can you make a *minimal* but still complete (e.g. `main()` of 20 lines) example that shows the problem?

Comment: hey @Flexo just updated the code. The problem is less likely to lie in the code because in essence it's the RtMidi probe/output library example, and has worked in previous linux environment settings(ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: Sanity check question then: are you sure your RtMidi library is built with ALSA/Jack support? Does `strace` or similar show anything important failing?

Comment: yes rtmidi is build to support [these](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/index.html#compiling) nothing seems to fail. It just does not find any output ports!

Comment: I know that I will repeat the previous question, but could you please post output of ldd on rtmidi library you use to be sure that it links to alsa library?